# Line Elements for $n$-dimensional hyperspheres

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I'm currently in the process of deriving the components of the Riemann Curvature Tensor for a 3-sphere using the Cartan Equations. The line element I'm starting with is:

$$ ds^2 = \frac{dr^2}{1-r^2/R^2}  + r^2 d\phi^2 + r^2\sin^2(\phi) d\theta^2 $$

During this procedure, differentiation of these terms is necessary, but the $R$ term is actually defined as another term involving $r$ to simplify the original line element to derive the one above. Now, the crux of this whole question is:

Do I simply differentiate $R$ with respect to $r$, or must its original definition be taken into account? In other words, do I treat $R$ just like $r$?

I've consulted several other sources on this, and they appear to do just this, but I'm not particularly comfortable with this as $R$ is a term involving $r$, NOT $r$ itself!!

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Hi Keith, I've converted your equation Mathjax to make it look nicer. Do you really mean $r^2/R^2$? Shouldn't it just be $r/R$?

Comment: Hi John!! Thanks for the conversion!! :-) And yes, I did forget the ^2!!!! It definitely states r^2/R^2 in the original line element, but when you derive the basis one forms for the (somewhat convoluted!!) calculation, the square root is taken so it does become r/R as you said!

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand your question, but it appears you're using $(r, \theta, \phi)$ as coordinates. If $R$ is a function of $r$, then any differentiation with respect to $r$ is performed just as in ordinary calculus, using the expression for $R$ as a function of $r$. (And if that's excessively messy, you can write $dR/dr$ or $R'(r)$ to represent the derivative, and express your calculations in terms of dR/dr$.)